# Java Get the List of an Object from another Class

Tags: java

I'm having two classes : WorldOfRobots and Robot (abstract). Both are public. World of robots is basically an arraylist of Robot.
Then I have a class telebot which is an extension of Robot.
I'm trying to build a method in the class Telebot which will identify and get the list of robots where the current object Telebot is.
For example:
I create 2 World of Robots (wor1 and wor2) and then 1 telebot (r1).
I add r1 in wor1.
I'd like to get a way to get the list of robots of wor1 in a method of the class telebot.

Here is a bit of code.

```
abstract class Robot {
// content
}

public class Telebot extends Robot
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private WorldOfRobots wor;

    public Telebot(String newName, String newDirection)
    {
        super(newName, newDirection);
    }

    public void something {

        // here I'm trying to get the list
        wor = new WorldOfRobots();
        ArrayList<Robot> robots = wor.getList();
        // Unfortunately this solution doesn't work cause I'm creating a new WOR. What I want is to get the WOR where the Telebot belong.
    }

}

public class WorldOfRobots {

// List of robots
private ArrayList<Robot> robots;

    public WorldOfRobots() {
    robots = new ArrayList<Robot>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Robot> getList() {
        return robots;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could pass an additional parameter `WorldOfRobots wor`  to the `Telebot` constructor and assign it there.

Comment: i am smelling cyclic dependency here, maybe you could elaborate on your use case as to what is the use of wor in telebot class. What do you want to achieve with association of telebot and world of robots.

Comment: I'd like to loop my list of Robots to check if my telebot share some attributes with another. Note that normally, there is only one WoR and multiple robots can be added to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your class to something like this ...

```
public class Telebot extends Robot {

//your code and constructer here

public void something(WorldofRobots container){
  //this is the list containing your instance of telerobot, use it as you like
}

}
```

Now from outside classes you can invoke `robotInstance.something(listOfRobot);`
I am not sure how your classes are exactly interacting so I cannot expand on using this method more.

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class Robot {
private WorldOfRobots world;

public void setWorld(WorldOfRobots world)
{
    this.world=world;
}
// content
}

public class Telebot extends Robot
{
    public Telebot(String newName, String newDirection)
    {
        super(newName, newDirection);
    }   
    public void doSomething()
    {
        world.doSomethingElse();
    }

}

public class WorldOfRobots {

// List of robots
private ArrayList<Robot> robots;

    public WorldOfRobots() {
    robots = new ArrayList<Robot>();
    }
    public void addRobot(Robot robot)
    {
        robots.add(robot);
        robot.setWorld(this);
    }

}
```

Storing a reference for the `WorldOfRobots` in the `Robot` class is reasonable in this case. If you want a robot to belong to multiple `WorldOfRobots` then change the world varible to List.